# How to get all records when using pagination

Tags: cakephp

Let's say I set a `limit` of 10 per page on a set of records retrieved with `$results = $this->paginate('ModelName')`. The total number of records matching the paginate/find parameter is 30, so 10 records show up on each of the pages. When I look at `$results`, it contains only 10 records displayed on the page.

Is there a way to get all 30 records in the view without having to separately do something like  `$allResults = find('all', $params)` followed by `$this->set('everything', $allResults)`?

Comment: So you want to paginate without paginating? If you bake your views you will have pagination links to get to the second and third page in your example. That is how you can access the rest of the records.

Comment: Not exactly. I already have the 2nd and 3rd page links at the bottom of the view. I want pagination for the user, but I want to allow the user to perform an operation that uses the entire set (30) of records on any given page.

Comment: Then allow him to modify "limit" param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing some of the pagination parameters that can be used to retrieved all of the 30 records from the view via a form to an action.

So, the user clicks on a form on the view that submits hidden variables to an action, where the whole set of 30 records are retrieved and desired operation is performed. Then, the page is redirected to the previously paginated view.